# Unable to mount volume in azure app service?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-app-service-plans

I am trying to deploy a Node SDK on azure app service through docker container. In my sdk, I have mounted a connection file & written a docker-compose for this. But when I deploy it by azure I get below error.

> InnerException: Docker.DotNet.DockerApiException, Docker API responded
>   with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"invalid
>   volume specification: ':/usr/src/app/connection.json'"}

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  node:
    container_name: node
    image: dhiraj1990/node-app:latest
    command: [ "npm", "start" ]
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot/connection.json:/usr/src/app/connection.json
```

connection.json is present at this path `/site/wwwroot`.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:8

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
```

Please tell me what is the issue ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:**

The problem is that you cannot mount a file to the persistent storage, it should be a directory. So the correct volumes should set like below:

```
volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot:/usr/src/app
```

And you also need to enable the persistent storage in your Web app for the container by setting the environment variable `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=TRUE`. For more details, see [Add persistent storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app#add-persistent-storage).

The persistent storage is just used to persist your data from your container. And if you want to share your files to the container, I will suggest you mount the Azure File share to the container. But you need to pay attention to the caution here:

> Linking an existing directory in a web app to a storage account will
>   delete the directory contents.

So you need to mount the Azure File Share to a new directory without necessary files. And you can get more details about the steps in [Configure Azure Files in a Container on App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage). It not only supports Windows containers but also supports Linux containers.

Comment: Still getting issue InnerException: Docker.DotNet.DockerApiException, Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"invalid volume specification: ':/usr/src/app'"}

Comment: @DhirajKumar Do you run a Linux image? Can you enable the persistent storage in the environment variable?

Comment: I chose linux while creating app service

Comment: @DhirajKumar Can you share your Dockerfile for the image you use?

Comment: check docker file

Comment: @DhirajKumar It seems no error in the Dockerfile, and when you change the docker-compose into what I said, then it also no problem. Two more questions, can you run it well locally? Do you enable persistent storage in the web app environment variable?

Comment: I am able to run docker-compose file locally. but in that file path is different

Comment: @DhirajKumar What do you mean the file path is different?

Comment: localpath - ./connection.json:/usr/src/app

Comment: @DhirajKumar I think it will overwrite the files in /use/src/app if you use the volumes like `./connection.json:/usr/src/app`.

Comment: @DhirajKumar How do you deploy the file to Azure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197856/discussion-between-charles-xu-and-dhiraj-kumar).

Comment: Kindly update your answer with steps for creating persistent storage.I had to create persistent  storgae to get this done.

Comment: @DhirajKumar Well, I will update the answer. Do you mean to mount the Azure File share steps? Or just the persistent storage?

Comment: all steps so that a user can get better idea

Comment: this solutions dosen't work to me , i'am not able to start the container